# Bonus traps from Essen Spielmesse 2019, what are the rules for them?

Tags: obscurio

I was at the Essen Spielmesse 2019 and enjoyed the game Obscurio. I bought the game and at the booth they gave us some bonus traps to use in the game. However no rules were given with the traps and we have no idea how to use them. We could hazard a guess, but would love some official guidelines on how they should be played if they are pulled out of the bag.

[image: Picture of the three bonus traps]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Someone asked the same question on boardgamegeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2300507/additional-traps-spiel-19-essen), and someone found the [rules](http://www.libellud.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/OBS_RULES_TOKENS_PROMO_EN.pdf) on the publisher's website, they are:

- Music hall (Music note):

  - Affects step 2 and 4
  - The wizards can only communicate by singing, the Grimoire is not affected by this token
- Raving mad (Cards with the arrows around the outside and question mark on them):

  - Affects step 2
  - Take the loyalty card from each wizard and mix them facedown. Deal them to each Wizard. This token is then removed from the game and cannot be pulled again
- Aphonia (Speech bubble with the X in it):

  - Affects step 2 and 4
  - The wizards can only communicate through gestures and mimes, they may not talk, sing, nor make any verbal noise of any kind. The Grimoire is not affected by this token.